# Eslint plugins for node + typescript that work from the box

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

Right now I manually add plugins like eslint, n, security, import, sonarjs and some of them require manual fixes for typescript. Seems that many people solve the same problem many times, but I didn't find a solution that just works out of the box. Can you recommend me some solution that solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend `@antfu`'s solution to make one config package to rule all other config packages

https://github.com/antfu/eslint-config

I use it with [eslint-define-config](https://github.com/Shinigami92/eslint-define-config) to simplify rule customisations

```
|- package.json
|   {
|     "devDependencies": {
|       "@antfu/eslint-config": "^0.37.0",
|       "eslint": "^8.36.0",
|       "eslint-define-config": "^1.17.0"
|     }
|   }
|- tsconfig.json
|- .eslintrc.cjs
|     process.env.ESLINT_TSCONFIG = 'tsconfig.json' // for @antfu ts-aware rules
|     const { defineConfig } = require('eslint-define-config')
|     module.exports = defineConfig({
|       root: true,
|       extends: '@antfu',
|       rules: {
|         /* has autocompletions and typecheck */
|       }
|     }
```

For minor customisations you can easily use rules, for major ones you may make a fork.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks good, will give it a try soon.